# VideoCapture() using a HDMI USB2.0 capture card

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to get video capture from a HDMI capture card. The code is extremely simple:

```
    import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried with a webcam and it works perfectly, however the HDMI capture device wouldn't work. (through USB 2.0)
I'm getting the error

```
[ WARN:0] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (376) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::OnReadSample videoio(MSMF): OnReadSample() is called with error status: -2147024809
[ WARN:0] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (388) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::OnReadSample videoio(MSMF): async ReadSample() call is failed with error status: -2147024809
[ WARN:1] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (1022) CvCapture_MSMF::grabFrame videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -2147024809
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Would appreciate some help!

Comment: Linux or Windows?

Comment: Are you able to use the capture card with VLC?

Comment: In Windows there is a bug in the DirectShow videocapture source code of OpenCV, where they try to capture in the fast "preview_mode" even if that is not available on the device. It's  just a single line of code to change to make for example a Hauppauge analog usb video card working with OpenCV.

Comment: https://answers.opencv.org/answers/56188/revisions/